# How to get integers from a specific string using regexp?

Tags: java, regex

I have some sample text

```
# HELP aaasd asdads
# TYPE ASDA dasdas
goodmetric_total{"camel-1"} 777.0
# HELP qqq www
# TYPE eee rrr
badmetric_total{"camel-1"} 888.0
```

I will need to get numbers from a specific string. Using String.format, I will substitute the values I need. For example `goodmetric_total`.

How do I write a regexp to get only a numerical value?
At the moment, I have solutions for searching string first.

```
^goodmetric.+\d+
```

And already in this line look for numbers.

I think you can do all this in one operation.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you need to get `777.0` or `777.0` and `1`? from `goodmetric_total{"camel-1"} 777.0`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry. I only need to get a value like 777

Comment: Then you could use a non-regex approach, or a regex one with a pattern similar to `^goodmetric.+ (\d+)(?:\.0)?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/2waYml/1)) (where you capture the int part of the number into Group 1).

Comment: Why not just use the [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method? `String value=""; if (line.trim().startsWith("goodmetric_total")) { value = line.split("\\s+")[1]; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex approach with

```
(?m)^goodmetric.*\h(\d+)(?:\.0+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2waYml/2). *Details*:

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `goodmetric` - a string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\h` - a horizontal whitespace
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?:\.0+)?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more `0` chars
- `$` - end of a line (due to `(?m)` modifier = `Pattern.MULTILINE`).

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/dUMjlu):

```java
String s = "# HELP aaasd asdads\n# TYPE ASDA dasdas\ngoodmetric_total{\"camel-1\"} 777.0\n# HELP qqq www\n# TYPE eee rrr\nbadmetric_total{\"camel-1\"} 888.0";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^goodmetric.*\\h(\\d+)(?:\\.0+)?$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Comment: I am very grateful to you for the explanation!